# Find the source of a DNS query on Windows Server

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-controller

I have a machine running Windows Server 2012 R2 that is generating invalid DNS queries.

The server's only IP address is 192.168.1.20/24 and is configured statically. It is configured for a single DNS server, 192.168.1.1, which is also the default gateway. Windump confirms that most DNS queries from this server are sent to the correct DNS server.

Occasionally, however, windump shows a DNS query sent to another DNS server, that looks like this:

```
12:37:54.397958 IP 192.168.1.20.51359 > 192.168.0.10.53:  23110+ [1au] A? clientservices.googleapis.com. (58)
12:44:29.037933 IP 192.168.1.20.51174 > 192.168.0.10.53:  37409+ A? www.skyres.ca. (31)
12:44:35.528727 IP 192.168.1.20.52753 > 192.168.0.10.53:  11591+ [1au] A? ns1.secureserver.net. (49)
12:52:46.473216 IP 192.168.1.20.51157 > 192.168.0.10.53:  25493+ A? safebrowsing.googleapis.com. (45)
12:52:53.761783 IP 192.168.1.20.51157 > 192.168.0.10.53:  25493+ [1au] A? safebrowsing.googleapis.com. (56)
```

It could be pure coincidence, but our office has a Windows domain controller and DNS server whose IP address is 192.168.0.10, however the server in question (192.168.1.20) is at a remote location and has no access to our domain controller. In fact, 192.168.1.20 is a domain controller on another domain.

It is possible that 192.168.1.20 was once located on the same network and domain as 192.168.0.10, but that was before I joined this company 8 months ago.

Any idea as to why 192.168.1.20 is trying to query a DNS server that Windows is ostensibly not configured to use, and to which it has no access?

Could somebody suggest a way to trace the software origin of this DNS request within the server?

Comment: From the names requested, it seems to be a web browsing session, by Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: Chrome and Firefox do not show in the list of installed programs, however I did find a disconnected user called 'test' that was running a Google Installer process. I logged out that user and will see if the queries persist.

Comment: Backdoors and trojans are known to communicate with the masterbots via spoofed dns requests. Have you analyzed if your security has been breached?

Comment: Does 192.168.1.20 have the Windows DNS Server installed?  If so, you might need to check its configuration.  I assume the two domains do not have a trust relationship?

Comment: 192.168.1.20 does not have DNS Server installed and there is no trust relationship.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `netstat -nba` to get the processes opening connexions.
The key part of this command is `-b` that shows you the executable evolved in actual connexion.

Comment: This looks like a useful suggestion. I'm no longer with that organisation, so I'm not able to investigate further (unless I run into this again on another server).